# Curve of all points C for which $|AC|=|BC|$ and $BC \parallel g$ ...?

Tags: geometry, math-software

sorry for the title being a little bit weird. The full question is:

Let's take two non parallel lines $g$ and $h$ and a fixed(!) point $A \not \in g$.
Now take a look at all triangles $ABC$ for which:

- $|AC|=|BC|$
- $B \in g$
- $|BC| \parallel  h$

Is there a specific curve of all those points C? I'd like to get a visualization of them wit GeoGebra and already tried, however I was not capable of finising it (maybe you've got some advice for me).
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: What is the purpose of line $h$? It is not used.

Comment: @ChrisApostol Thank you very much for this hint! THere was a mistake in my papers, It definitely should be $BC \parallel h$!

Comment: I used the locus function in geogebra and it looks like some kind of hyperbola.

Comment: @E.Girgin Thank you - what you have posted before (now deleted) - doesn't it also work in that case? If neither point $B$ nor the line $g$ are fixed and I move both, I get the whole $R^2$ ?